# How to use PostGIS extensions from within Grounghog?

Tags: haskell, orm, postgis

I am writing a haskell project using groundhog (as ORM) and PostgreSQL (as RDBMS). Everything looks fine but now I am adding some PostGIS fields to some tables. I have used Python before and SqlAlchemy has an extension called GeoAlchemy, which provides very good support of PostGIS which makes coding very easy. Is there any similar extension for Groundhog?